# How to Create new Database from Existing Data Base in c#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I want to create a new database using c#. I just want to pass database name from user interface and for that database name i want to run a sql script of database for creating the same schema of that script for new database.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking or what you've tried. Have a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You are going to have to try significantly harder if you want to continue to ask questions here.  This one is rubbish.

Comment: I have a database script and i want to run that script using c# for creating the database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not have exactly whay you intend to do, but I have done some functionality to seed some default data to the master tables.

//sql file location

```
private static readonly string IndexScriptSeedMasterDataLocation = "SqlSeedMasterData.sql";
```

In the function I have :

```
 private static void SeedMasterData ( IpDataContext context, string databaseName)
{
  context.Database.CreateIfNotExists();
  var sqlContent = Content(IndexScriptSeedMasterDataLocation);
  var modifiedSqlScript = sqlContent.Replace("@DatabaseName", databaseName);
  context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(modifiedSqlScript);
}
```

// Content function :

```
private static string Content(string fileLocation)
{
 using (var stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(fileLocation))
    {
      if (stream == null)
       {
          return string.Empty;
       }
       var streamReader = new StreamReader(stream);
       return streamReader.ReadToEnd();
     }
}
```